# How can I avoid the repetition of "population" in this text?

Tags: sentence-structure, repetition

In the following sentence, is it OK if I remove the second "population" from the sentence?

> 1. Overall, the Italian population was older than the Yemenis population.
> 2. Overall, the Italian population was older than the Yemenis.

I think we do not need to repeat the second population, Am I correct? In fact, I think that second sentence is better than the first one.

Comment: I see the problem here stemming from the use of "age of a population". I don't think a population can have an "age".  It can have a size, it can have an age structure, but only people have an age.  Would a rephrasing like "The median age of Italians was more than that of Yemenis" Or "Yemenis were younger than Italians, on average"

Answer (score 1):

The second is not quite correct.

You could say

> Overall, the Italian population was older than that of Yemen.

In the first sentence I think you need

> Overall, the Italian population was older than the Yemeni population.

since you are modifying  to the single noun "population", not the people as a collection.

Answer (score 1):

The answer has to do with the part of speech of the word **Yemenis**.

If it is an adjective, similar to British, French or Italian, 2. is fine.

If, however, Yemenis is the plural form of a proper noun, equivalent to Britons or Germans, it doesn't work.

By way of illustration, it's fine to say:

**The Italian population is older than the German.**

But wrong to say:

**The Italian population is older than the Germans.**

I suspect that the correct way to phrase the sentence (to avoid the repetition in 1.) would be:

**The Italian population is older than the Yemeni.**

But I am not sufficiently familiar with the use of Yemeni and Yeminis.